# How to nest a variable inside a variable?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, ksh

I have a scenario in which I need to execute the below statement.

```
air sandbox run $AI_PLAN/Sam_22.plan
```

For the above command AI should be fetched from a command.

```
> echo $PREFIX
AI
```

I tried the below ways

```
air sandbox run $`echo $PREFIX`_PLAN/Sam_22.plan
```

returned error : `File not found`

```
dollar_prefix=$`echo $PREFIX`
air sandbox run ${dollar_prefix}_PLAN/Sam_22.plan
```

returned error : `File not found`

Please let me know where am I going wrong in the above coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to `eval` something:

```
PREFIX=AI
AI_PLAN=some_directory
eval directory=\$${PREFIX}_PLAN
air sandbox run $directory/Sam_22.plan
```

Answer (score 0):

try using command substitution:

```
$(command ...)_PLAN
```

Lets suppose the program `make_prefix` is in your path.  Then:

```
> make_prefix
AI
> echo $(make_prefix)
AI
> echo $(make_prefix)_PLAN
AI_PLAN
```

Comment: Hi Foo Bah, I did not understand clearly can you please eloborate.

Comment: Hi Foo, this did not work out it is giving error message.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It unclear what you actually want to have happen, but I can guess that you probably want something like

```
air sandbox ${${PREFIX}_PLAN}/Sam_22.plan
```

This will take the value of the variable PREFIX (`AI` in your case?) and append a `_PLAN`, and use THAT as the name of a variable to fetch

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for answering I am getting below error    > echo ${PREFIX}
AI

> echo ${PREFIX}_PLAN
AI_PLAN

> echo ${${PREFIX}_PLAN}
-ksh: syntax error: `!' unexpected